# What would be the best way to send email twice to the same email address with different Salutation, when email is the unique identifier

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect

We have the following architecture in our Salesforce CRM as displayed in the diagram and this was integrated with Salesforce Marketing Cloud.

As we have Emails in separate object and multiple emails related to each contact, we had email's as the unique identifier for Marketing Cloud.

My question is, in some cases we have to send same email form the same send which is where a Son and a parent has the same email address but different Salutation. But email being the unique identifier the email is being flagged as duplicate.

What would be the best way to send email twice to the same email address with different Salutation.

[image]

Comment: So, how frequent is "in some cases"? Once-per-month solution might just be "have someone do it manually", two-hundred-per-day solution is more "consider using something other than email as your unique identifier"; in between there might be "add a second 'alternate salutation' field", and set up a second email template that uses that instead.

Comment: it is almost every week.
So if we have a alternate Salutation field and setup an email template with this alternate field, how can we send multiple emails with this approach from the same email send?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so. Rereading your use case, I doubt it's actually *necessary* to send the email twice; instead, make it clear that the email is relevant to both people using the address.

Alternatively, you can try tinkering with the email address formatting so that it "counts" as different without actually going off into the void. Gmail in particular allows for "name+something@gmail.com" to go to the same place as "name@gmail.com", so you potentially could have two contact records with "name+father@gmail.com" and "name+son@gmail.com" without having to resort to extra fields (or objects).

But the original intermediate solution I mentioned in the comments goes roughly as follows:

1. Create an "Alternate Salutation" field on your contact; field type, visibility, and so on should be as close to identical to the original "Salutation" field as possible.
2. Fill the field in for the contacts that have one.
3. Clone whatever email template(s) you're using that need to go twice to the same email address.
4. Edit those cloned templates so that where they have a "salutation" merge field, they instead have the "Alternate Salutation" merge field.
5. Clone whatever list you're using to send your mass emails, and add a filter of "Alternate Salutation isn't blank". If this wasn't a dynamic list to start, this will take a while (as will any other sweeping changes to that list).
6. Whenever you need to send email to the first list, also send it to the cloned list from step 5, using the cloned template from step 4.

Comment: Thanks Stephen for the very detailed answer, Alternate Salutation makes more sense for our use case.